# RestFB getting Conversations

Tags: java, comments, restfb

Iam using restfb to get in touch with Facebook from our application.

I have link to the conversation

https://www.facebook.com/prasannapatireddy/posts/234992897106899?comment_id=263969987542523

Now what I need is using above link I have to find out the Attachments if any in this conversation.

How can we do this in Java.

I tried below but didn't work
'
Connection myFeed = facebookClient
                .fetchConnection("https://www.facebook.com/prasannapatireddy/posts/234992897106899?comment_id=263969987542523",Comment.class);

Please Help.

Thanks & Regards,
Prasanna

Comment: Can some one please help me over here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the information in your call which fields you need. And you cannot use the perma link of a comment you see on Facebook, this is all about the Graph API.

```
Connection<Comment> commentConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnettion("<comment_id>", 
       Comment.class, Parameter.with("fields", "attachment"));
```

The comment id should be fetched via graph api or with some luck you can try to build it by hand.